# Trying to change how my code prints

Tags: c

I am new at programming and i am trying to change the format of my code when i run it, when ran it looks like this:

```
Enter Initial account balance: 1000

Enter  annual interest rate: 2

Enter number of years: 10
Year Daily   Weekly  Monthly Quarterly Annually
---- ------- ------- ------- --------- --------
 0 1000.00
 1 1020.26
 2 1040.92
 3 1062.01
 4 1083.52
 5 1105.47
 6 1127.86
 7 1150.71
 8 1174.02
 9 1197.80
 10 1222.07
    1000.00
     1020.53
     1041.49
     1062.87
     1084.70
     1106.97
     1129.70
     1152.89
     1176.56
     1200.72
     1225.38
       1000.00
       1021.58
       1043.63
       1066.15
       1089.16
       1112.67
       1136.68
       1161.21
       1186.28
       1211.88
       1238.03
         1000.00
         1024.90
         1050.42
         1076.58
         1103.39
         1130.87
         1159.03
         1187.89
         1217.47
         1247.79
         1278.86
           1000.00
           1040.40
           1082.43
           1126.16
           1171.66
           1218.99
           1268.24
           1319.48
           1372.79
           1428.25
           1485.95

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 4.569 s
Press any key to continue.
```

after reviewing my code i understand why it prints like that but instead i would want it to look something like this:

```
Year Daily   Weekly  Monthly Quarterly Annually
---- ------- ------- ------- --------- --------

  0  1000.00 1000.00 1000.00 1000.00   1000.00
  1  100x.xx 100x.xx 100x.xx 100x.xx   100x.xx
  2  10xx.xx ...
```

is there a way to change how it prints without changing much of my code? here is my original code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

int c = 0;
double initial_bal, num_years;
double interest_rate;
double userVal[5];
userVal[0] = (365.0);
userVal[1] = (365/7.0);
userVal[2] = (365/30.0);
userVal[3] = (365/90.0);
userVal[4] = (365/365.0);
int i = 0;

printf("Enter Initial account balance: ");
scanf("%lf", &initial_bal);
double bal = initial_bal;

printf("\nEnter  annual interest rate: ");
scanf("%lf", &interest_rate);
interest_rate = interest_rate/100;

printf("\nEnter number of years: ");
scanf("%lf", &num_years);

printf("Year Daily   Weekly  Monthly Quarterly Annually\n"
"---- ------- ------- ------- --------- --------\n");

printf(" 0 %.2f\n", initial_bal);
i=i+1;
while (i <= num_years) {
        double new_rate = interest_rate/userVal[0];
        for (c = 0; c <= userVal[0]; c++) {
                double addVal = new_rate*initial_bal;
                initial_bal = addVal+initial_bal;
                }
        printf (" %d %.2f \n", i, initial_bal);
        i = i + 1;
        c = 0;
        }
initial_bal = bal;
i=0;
printf("    %.2f\n", initial_bal);
i=i+1;
while (i <= num_years) {
        double new_rate = interest_rate/userVal[1];
        for (c = 0; c <= userVal[1]; c++) {
                double addVal = new_rate*initial_bal;
                initial_bal = addVal+initial_bal;
                }
        printf ("     %.2f \n", initial_bal);
        i = i + 1;
        c = 0;
        }
initial_bal = bal;
i=0;
printf("       %.2f\n", initial_bal);
i=i+1;
while (i <= num_years) {
        double new_rate = interest_rate/userVal[2];
        for (c = 0; c <= userVal[2]; c++) {
                double addVal = new_rate*initial_bal;
                initial_bal = addVal+initial_bal;
                }
        printf ("       %.2f \n", initial_bal);
        i = i + 1;
        c = 0;
        }
initial_bal = bal;
i=0;
printf("         %.2f\n", initial_bal);
i=i+1;
while (i <= num_years) {
        double new_rate = interest_rate/userVal[3];
        for (c = 0; c <= userVal[3]; c++) {
                double addVal = new_rate*initial_bal;
                initial_bal = addVal+initial_bal;
                }
        printf ("         %.2f \n", initial_bal);
        i = i + 1;
        c = 0;
        }
initial_bal = bal;
i=0;
printf("           %.2f\n", initial_bal);
i=i+1;
while (i <= num_years) {
        double new_rate = interest_rate/userVal[4];
        for (c = 0; c <= userVal[4]; c++) {
                double addVal = new_rate*initial_bal;
                initial_bal = addVal+initial_bal;
                }
        printf ("           %.2f \n", initial_bal);
        i = i + 1;
        c = 0;
        }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Merge the 5 loops in one

Comment: Fill a matrix and print it after elaborations.

Answer (score 1):

Set up an array of num_years strings. Initialise them all to the empty string, "", but give them big enough char buffers, say 1024.  Then replace your printf calls with sprintf to a temporary buffer, and call strcat on the correct string. Finally print them all out at the end.

To set up the array.

```
char **output;

output = malloc(num_years * sizeof(char *));
if(!output)
   /* out of memory, probably just exit */;
/* always do this for safety */
for(i=0;i<num_years;i++)
   output[i] = 0;
for(i=0;i<num_years;i++)
{
   output[i] = malloc(1024);
   if(!output[i])
     /* you're out of memory - probably just exit for now */;
   strcpy(output[i], "");
}
```

Now we've got num_years strings with a capacity of 1024 bytes, and initialised to the empty string. We then address them by index and build them up with strcat().

Finally we print them all out, and free them, not forgetting to also free the char ** itself.

Comment: char num_years[1024] = "";

Comment: and do you have an example on using sprintf and strcat, more specifically calling strcat on a certain string

Comment: No. I'll add an example.

Comment: Ok I'm slowly understanding what you are doing. So Next we address them by index and build them up. Strcat (output[i], something); then printf("something, %s", output[i]); please correct me if I'm wrong. As for all of this is new to me

Comment: i still need help. i cant seem to finish the code. i've been looking up how to build them up with strcat(), and printing them all out, and freeing them. but i cant seem to understand it